# Часы moment.js

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как можно зделать такие же часы как на сайте momentjs.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Часы на CSS3](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/css3-clock/)

Comment: с помощью этого можно создать такие же часы с таким же дизайном который там? разница лишь в css?

Comment: что на Momentjs.com, что в моей ссылке часы написаны на чистом CSS. Поэтому да - разница лишь в CSS, а ещё большая разница в описании анимации. Если вам нужны именно такие часы с именно таким дизайном - так оттуда и заберите их. Возьмите оттуда CSS, а HTML разметку возьмите с div.watch.
Единственное но: это CSS часы. Это значит, что стартовую позицию стрелок надо рассчитывать вручную, т.е. CSS должен генерироваться динамически на сервере.